# Is order of vector elements preserved when appending?

Tags: c++, vector

As the title already indicates I'd like to know whether the internal order of vector elements can change *only by appending* elements to the vector.

Here I refer to both the possibility of order-change *with* and *without* reallocation, concerning two different cases:

1. storing the pointers to a class, like:

   ```
   vector<A*> vec;    //for some class A;
   vec.push_back(new A());
   ```
2. storing elements of a class, like:

   ```
   vector<A> vec;    //for some class A;
   vec.push_back(A());
   ```

If it is the case that the order may change is there a possibility to notice that such a change happened (for example some flags are set, ...)?

Is it also possible to notice whether the vector was reallocated?

Are there other containers (dynamic in size) which preserve definitely the internal order of any elements (like a list)?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: `Is it also possible to notice whether the vector was reallocated?` - Yes, when `capacity` function gives a different result. Be aware that reallocation can COPY the elements to a new area. The elements are in the same order, but might not be the same objects in memory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is order of vector elements preserved when appending?

Yes.

> Are there other containers (dynamic in size) which preserve definitely the internal order of any elements (like a list)?

All [sequence containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/SequenceContainer) in C++ preserve internal order. All others don’t necessarily (especially associative containers).

Comment: @jrh Thanks, fixed.